# Get list of all possible command line arguments for an exe

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, powershell

Is there anyway for me to get the list of available command line arguments for an exe? I need to create a Powershell script that start the Relius Agent Manager program, but this program requires database login and password info to load.

I can obtain the login/pass info, but I need to know the names of the argument I'll need to pass them through.

It doesn't matter if I use Powershell or C# to retrieve the list of arguments, I just need to know their darn names.

I read up on the Process class in C# but I don't see anything that will actually list the available arguments, only how to list what was passed when a process was started.

Comment: AFAIK this should not be possible in any programming language. What you can do however, is open CMD/bash/whatever and run `<myprogram.exe> --help` or `<myprogram.exe> /?` and see if that gives you the arguments availible.

Comment: No, I don't think that's possible. For any program, the 'number of parameters' is nothing but strings.
In C, these parameters are passed as int argc, char *argv.

To make the long story short, other than parsing a possible 'help' output, you're stuck.

Comment: I agree with the other commenters. You're at the mercy of parsing usage output.  If the exe even provides it. And this is one of nice benefits of a PowerShell command over a command line exe. PowerShell supplies the parameter parsing engine for all PowerShell commands which provides parsing consistency (- vs /), positional parameters, parameter name disambiguation, and the ability to get parameter info e.g. `Get-Command Get-Process -Syntax`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all of your help. I was able to solve it by having someone start it manually and then log in, and then I checked this list of all running processes with this command:

"WMIC /OUTPUT:C:\ProcessList.txt PROCESS get Caption,Commandline,Processid"

I was then able to find exactly what was passed when it was run from the file that command generated and execute that command in PowerShell using something like:

$exp = "&'C:\path\to\the\exe.exe' /param1 /param2 /param3" 
invoke-expression $exp

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to query the supported command line arguments. Try running the program from a command prompt with no arguments, with an invalid argument, with /h, /?, -h, --help and similar arguments to see if one of these prompts the program to output a list of allowed arguments.

Answer (score 1):

search for universal silent switch finder. it is actually possible to do programmatically but requires deep diving into binary executable.  if interested check http://code.google.com/p/pefile/wiki/PEiDSignatures